# How to load data from S3 Bucket to MySQL RDS Database?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

But for every file in bucket there is a table in RDS and particular file data should go to particular table only.
Whenever file uploads in bucket then it should trigger and should go to RDS table.

For this I have used Lambda function but for me the file data is going in to every table in RDS but I need that data should go to particular table only.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Here is the code

```
import json
import boto3
import csv
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import errorcode
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    # print(event)
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    csv_file = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    csv_file_obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=csv_file)
    lines = csv_file_obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split()
    results_emp1 = []
    for row in csv.DictReader(lines):
        results_emp1.append(row.values())
    print(results_emp1)
    
    results_emp2 = []
    for row in csv.DictReader(lines):
        results_emp2.append(row.values())
    print(results_emp2)
    
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='xxxxxxxxxx',database='employeedb',user='xxxxxx',password='xxxxxxx')
    
    mysql_emp1sql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO employee1 (empid, empname, empaddress) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(mysql_emp1sql_insert_query,results_emp1)
    connection.commit()
    print(cursor.rowcount, "Record inserted successfull into employee1 table")
    
    mysql_emp2sql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO employee2 (empid, empname, empaddress) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(mysql_emp2sql_insert_query,results_emp2)
    connection.commit()
    print(cursor.rowcount, "Record inserted successfull into employee2 table")
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Comment: Show the code that you have. It seems that this is a simple problem of extracting the table name from the object key passed in the Lambda invocation event.

Comment: Thank You for your response @Parsifal.
Here is the code and please check and help me.
Scenario : Whenever I upload a file in S3 bucket then the data in the file should go to the that particular table in RDS.

Comment: Does the key identify the table that will receive the inserts? If yes, then it seems a simple matter of changing your INSERT statement. _What, exactly, isn't working for you?

Comment: For example I have employee1.csv and employee2.csv  files and I have employee1 table and employee2 table in mysql RDS. So when I upload employee1.csv or employee2.csv file in s3 then the data is going to every table in RDS ... it is not going to particular table which I want.